# a three partite quantum state with maximum entanglement

Tags: entanglement

I thought the only three-partite states with maximum entanglement are GHZ and W states. but i found out the below state has maximum entanglement too

$\frac{1}{2}(\left| 111 \right>+\left| 100 \right>+\left| 010 \right>+\left| 001 \right>)$

I want to know what is name of this state? is there any article about it?